# Criar uma função recursiva em C que retorne o maior e o menor valor de um vetor

Tags: c

Galera, como eu posso resolver esse exercício?

1- na primeira linha o usuário tem que digitar o tamanho do vetor
2- na segunda linha, o usuário preenche com números inteiros 
3- fazer uma função recursiva que recebe por referência as variáveis de maior e menor valores. O vetor deverá ser alocado dinamicamente.

To apanhando muito sobre essa alocação dinamica.
Fiz um esboço aqui em baixo e to mais perdido que cego em tiroteio -.-

```
void procurar(int vetor[], int *tamanho, int *maior, int *menor){    

int i, j, aux; 

  for(i = 1; i < *tamanho; i++){ 
    j = i; 

    while((j != 0) && (*vetor[j] > *vetor[j - 1])) { 
      aux = *vetor[j]; 
      *vetor[j] = *vetor[j - 1]; 
      *vetor[j-1] = aux; 
      j--;     
    } 
  }

  *maior = *vetor[*tamanho];
  *menor = *vetor[0];
}



int main(){

    int tamanho, i, maior, menor;

    maior = 0;

    scanf("%d", &tamanho);

    int vetor[tamanho];

    for(i=0; i<tamanho; i++){
        scanf("%d", &vetor[i]);
    }

    procurar(&vetor, &tamanho, &maior, &menor);


    printf("%d %d", maior, menor);``

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sempre terá alguém que discorde, e que vai te dar a solução, mas me incomoda se fazer um algoritmo recursivo quando claramente um iterativo funciona melhor. No fundo é ensinar errado. (no sentido de usar a ferramenta menos adequada para o problema específico)

Answer (score 1):

Não sei a partir de qual versão do padrão C se pode alocar um vetor na pilha, como você fez, usando uma variável como índice do tamanho; ou é C99 ou C11. Mas se você quiser um código mais compatível com C89 (que, por exemplo, funciona com os compiladores da MSFT), você está mais bem arrumado usando `malloc()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* implementação de "procurar()" omitida */

int main() {
    int tamanho, i, maior, menor;
    int * vetor;

    if (scanf("%d", &tamanho) < 1 || tamanho < 1) {
        fputs("Não consegui ler o tamanho do vetor\n", stderr);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    vetor = malloc(tamanho * sizeof (int));
    if (vetor == NULL) {
        fputs("Não consegui alocar o vetor\n", stderr);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < tamanho; i ++) {
        if (scanf("%d", &vetor[i]) < 1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Não consegui ler o %dº valor do vetor\n", i + 1);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    }

    procurar(vetor, tamanho, &maior, &menor);
    fprintf("O maior número é %d e o menor, %d\n", maior, menor);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Quanto ao `procurar()` propriamente dito, é bom lembrar que recursão é uma implementação da técnica matemática de indução, então você tem que definir um *caso base* e um *passo indutivo.*  Como você está tratando de vetores, uma boa variável para induzir é o tamanho do vetor; então, nesse caso, o caso base é quando você tem um vetor de comprimento 1 e o passo indutivo é o resultado da função num subvetor do vetor atual (por exemplo, o vetor começando a partir do segundo elemento). Em miúdos:

```
void procurar(int vetor[], int tamanho, int * maior, int * menor) {
    if (tamanho == 1) { /* caso base */
        * maior = * menor = vetor[0];
    } else { /* passo indutivo */
        procurar(vetor + 1, tamanho - 1, maior, menor);
        if (vetor[0] > * maior) * maior = vetor[0];
        if (vetor[0] < * menor) * menor = vetor[0];
    }
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado @Wtrmute. Eu compilei seu código no DevC++ e tive que fazer umas pequenas alterações de acordo com que o meu exercício de faculdade pediu. Mas de resto, a função procurar que você fez está certinha, e foi muito útil para eu aprender. Brigadão :D